# How do I safely treat subungual hematoma? Tamarind seeds paste helps?

Tags: treatment-options, hematoma

Some say that grinding 'Tamarind seeds' soaked in water and applying it all over the toe and letting it dry for more than 8 hours, effectively - if not completely - removes the blackened blood under the nail by absorbing it. And it is repeated until it's completely removed.

Is this true?

I don't find any article or webpage that has both subungual hematoma and tamarind using google.

Is the heated paperclip treatment safe? Is it the only form of treatment that can be done at home?

Mine doesn't seem to be above 40% and it isn't paining. Will it go away if I just leave it like that?